# How can I implement a simple authorization scheme in .NET Core 2 for a REST app that reads in a token in headers and checks for authorization in redis

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to be able to create a simple authorization scheme where I can protect a given route using `[Authorize]`. I want to control what happens here. I very simply would like to check the headers for a field like `Authorization` and grab the `bearer` token and then manually review it and inject an identity for a single HTTP call. After this the identity is lost and any new calls require another authorization check.

I've been reading the .NET Core 2 documentation but haven't had much luck yet with the role, claim, or policy based authorization schemes outlined in the documentation.

In Java, this is pretty easily achieved via Spring MVC but how can I accomplish the same thing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

With some time spent in research I was able to find that the best practices are to use an existing scheme. I wasn't able to find a good example of a custom setup but most known schemes are well supported so I chose to use JWT authentication. It is very similar to what I wanted to do originally by generating a randomized token and using that for access to privileged request going forward.

This code works for me. It is a very simple example but it clearly shows how to login and then authenticate to a secured method.

You will want to change the private key and have a way of authenticating your users instead of the static hard-coded user check that I did below.

Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("THIS_IS_YOUR_SECRET_KEY_CREATE_SOMETHING_RANDOMIZED_AND_COMPLICATED"))
                    };
                });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
        }


 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                //app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });
        }
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using coreapi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

namespace coreapi.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return Json(new ErrorViewModel());
        }

        [Authorize]
        public IActionResult Secured()
        {
            ErrorViewModel model = new ErrorViewModel();
            model.RequestId = "secured works";

            return Json(model);
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return Json(new ErrorViewModel {RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier});
        }
    }
}
```

AuthController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using coreapi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace coreapi.Controllers
{
    public class AuthController
    {
        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Login([FromBody]LoginModel user)
        {
            if (user == null)
            {
                return new BadRequestObjectResult("Invalid client request");
            }

            if (user.EmailAddress == "bob@bobsburgers.com" && user.Password == "test123")
            {
                var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("THIS_IS_YOUR_SECRET_KEY_CREATE_SOMETHING_RANDOMIZED_AND_COMPLICATED"));
                var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

                // issuer and audience aren't currently being used
                var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
                    issuer: "https://localhost:8080",
                    audience: "https://localhost:8080",
                    claims: new List<Claim>(),
                    expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(5),
                    signingCredentials: signinCredentials
                );

                var tokenString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(tokeOptions);
                return new OkObjectResult(new { Token = tokenString });
            }
            else
            {
                return new UnauthorizedResult();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

LoginModel.cs

```
namespace coreapi.Models
{
    public class LoginModel
    {
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```